# Cannot get Annotation with Reflection Java

Tags: java, reflection, spring-data

I tried to put annotation to method and the retrieve the data inside it, but when I debug the code, I cannot get any annotations present.

This is may DatabaseSeederImpl, simple class that calls different services to seed data into database.

```
@Override
    public void seed() {
        seedData(SeedUserDto.class, userService);
        seedData(SeedCategoryDto.class, categoryService);
        seedData(SeedProductDto.class, productService);
    }

    private <S> void seedData(Class<?> dtoType, S service) {
        Arrays.stream(service.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Seed.class))
                .forEach(method -> {
                    try {
                        String fileName = method.getDeclaredAnnotation(Seed.class).fileName();
                        method.invoke(service, gson.fromJson(readJson(fileName), dtoType.arrayType()));
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is my annotation which targets methods and its retention policy is set to runtime.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Seed {
    String fileName();
}
```

And in my services, I set this annotation with proper value.

```
@Override
@Transactional
@Seed(fileName = "categories.json")
public void seedCategories(SeedCategoryDto[] categoryDtos) {
    if (categoryRepository.count() == 0) {
        List<Category> categories = Arrays.stream(categoryDtos)
                .filter(dataValidator::isValid)
                .map(dto -> modelMapper.map(dto, Category.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        categoryRepository.saveAll(categories);
    }
}
```

And this is my directory tree.

[image: Directory Tree]

Comment: Without a [mre] it's difficult to see the problem, but keep in mind that `getDeclaredMethods()` only returns methods directly declared in the class. If you've overridden the method and only the override has the annotation then the method on the interface won't have the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use getMethods rather than getDeclaredMethods it should work. Because getDeclaredMethods returns only the new methods of the class who were not in the superclass or superinterface.

And since your methods is @Override-ing, if you tried to debug, you would have noticed it was not even looping through that method